# onRestoreInstanceState() not being called when it is expected

Tags: android

I have run into some trouble lately with `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()`. I have multiple activities that use these methods to save state in the case that they are cleaned up by the system. Most of them work, except for one, and I have no idea why.

What specifically happens is this:

- I have my emulator running, and the dev tools setup to `destroy()` all activities when they are no longer visible. (So that I can prove that save/restore are working properly.)
- The Activity in question is started up, and I proceed to change some of its state.
- I start a new Activity, let it run for a moment, and then use the 'back' button to go to my previous Activity.
- Upon arriving back at the Activity in question, I notice that the default state is back, thus, it does not have the state it should.

I have noticed that the `onSaveInstanceState()` is called, `onCreate()` is called, but has a null bundle, and `onRestoreInstanceState()` is never called.

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: I'm sorry, I know this questions is for long time ago but how did you save the state of your activity? Would you please look at my question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26142255/retrieve-an-activity-after-time-out-warning-notification

Comment: Please check my [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62966140/2828651) to get it called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe I have figured out the issue, and it is with details that I did not disclose in the original question.

One of the things I am saving in my bundle is quite large (a 500x1000 pixel Bitmap).  When I removed that from my Bundle, everything else was saved, the onCreate() method was called with the Bundle, and onRestoreInstanceState() was called as well.

Thus I believe there is a maximum size Bundle that you can save in onSaveInstanceState(), which is not documented. (at least as far as I can tell)

Answer (score 3):

The dev tools setting you are using may not have the behavior you expect.

If you want to test `onSaveInstanceState()`/`onRestoreInstanceState()`, the simplest thing to do is to change the orientation (`<Ctrl>-<F11>`). By default, your activity is destroyed and recreated, using the instance state.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Something I didn't mention is that I have locked this Activity with the following attributes in the Manifest:

android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"

Comment: I tried changing orientation and that did called `onRestoreInstanceState()` method. But I don't restore variable in this method and still my EditText had previously entered values, instead of having nothing. Can you explain?

Comment: @Akash: There is a built-in implementation of `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` that handle obviously user-mutable widget state, like the text in an `EditText`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ok. Then why do we need to override these methods when those are handled by SDK?

Comment: @Akash: You only need to override those methods if you have *other* state that is *not* represented in something that the built-in `onSaveInstanceState()` will handle. Not everything in an activity is necessarily text in an `EditText`, for example.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ok. So lets say, I have activity where on button click I display a WebView, otherwise some other view is displayed. When app gets killed WebView was visible. So here should I save state, using flags, that WebView was displayed and display it on next invoke to `onRestoreInstanceState()`?

Comment: @Akash: I have no idea, as I am not the author of this activity and do not know what the expectations are. If you have further concerns in this area, ask a separate StackOverflow question, and explain **completely and precisely** what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

The explanation why `onRestoreInstanceState()` is not called (or more peciselly: when it is called) is given in another question's thread: [onSaveInstanceState () and onRestoreInstanceState ()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096169/onsaveinstancestate-and-onrestoreinstancestate)