# Why onRestoreInstanceState() never gets called

Tags: android

I am trying to save data in my activity and than restore it. 
I save data in on `onSaveInstanceState()` and then I try to restore the data in `onRestoreInstanceState()`.

I setup breakpoint, the method `onSaveInstanceState()` get called. But `onRestoreInstanceState()`  or `onCreate()` never did.

Here is my steps:

1. start my `Activity`.
2. press 'Home' button on the phone. `onSaveInstanceState()` get called.
3. Click the icon in the launcher and launch my `Activity` again.

At this time, only `onRestart()` get called. But not `onRestoreInstanceState()`  or `onCreate()`.

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well, if `onRestart()` is called, the value of the instance variables would be maintained by the application stack itself and thus you do not need to restore them.

`onCreate()` method is only called when your `Activity`'s `onStop()` is called and the process is killed.

Please refer the `Activity` life cycle  [Android Activity Life Cycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) for a clear understanding.

You may want to check whether the `onStop()` method is called and if your process is killed. I do no think that your process gets killed by the scenario which you have described.

the `onRestoreInstanceState()` method is very tricky. I do not know when exactly it is called but I saw it was called once while changing from Potrait to Landscape.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967435/onrestoreinstancestate-not-called-when-screen-wake-up - there's an answer what onRestoreInstanceState is for.

Comment: Your answer is not exactly accurate or it's at least unclear, because after onStop() either onRestart() is going to be called or onDestroy(). if onDestroy() is called then you're back to onCreate()

Comment: Thanks. onRestore... seems to be called when orientation is changed. Simplified things for me no end (+:

Answer (score 18):

From [doc:](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html)

> The system calls onRestoreInstanceState() only if there is a saved state to restore.

Comment: Why would onSaveInstanceState() be called if onRestoreInstanceState() wasn't going to ever be called?

It's crazy. If I switch to another activity the onSaveInstanceState() being called makes me think that I'll be able to access a saved instance state when I come back. But it never hits any of the restore/onCreate functions because it's restarting. It's poorly explained in documentation as well.

Answer (score 7):

I have asked similiar question earlier on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287237/simulate-killing-of-activity-in-emulator)

Here's some steps to test out `onRestoreInstanceState()`:

1. Press home screen
2. Kill the app through adb
3. Launch your app again

Answer (score 4):

Follow these steps (Using Android Studio):

1. Create New Logcat Filter, e.g. AppState
2. Launch the app on your emulator. You will see:

   I/AppState﹕ onCreate

   I/AppState﹕ onStart

   I/AppState﹕ onResume
3. Press Ctl-F12 to rotate the emulator. You will see:

   I/StateChange﹕ onPause

   I/StateChange﹕ onSaveInstanceState

   I/StateChange﹕ onStop

   I/StateChange﹕ onDestroy

   I/StateChange﹕ onCreate

   I/StateChange﹕ onStart

   I/StateChange﹕ onRestoreInstanceState

   I/StateChange﹕ onResume

This causes the destruction and recreation of the activity by making a configuration change to the device, such as rotating from portrait to landscape.

Answer (score 2):

See the link below for how to test `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` on a real device or in the emulator.

This method uses the AlwaysFinish setting, which is simpler and faster than killing processes. This method also provides `Activity`-level control rather than process level control:

http://bricolsoftconsulting.com/how-to-test-onsaveinstancestate-and-onrestoreinstancestate-on-a-real-device/

Comment: Your link is dead.

Answer (score -2):

This is my solution for real device so onRestoreInstanceState get it called.

1. in `manifest` on related activity remove this part `android:configChanges="orientation"`
2. in `manifest` on related activity remove this part`android:screenOrientation="portrait"`
3. in your activity remove this line if it's there    `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);`
4. on your device enable rotating from setting - display - auto rotate.

then run your app, rotate your device.
that's it.

Comment: Thanks, but does not work for an Android Emulator. Or perhaps this behaviour keeps changing over Android versions.