# Android application looses its fragments state

Tags: android, overlay, fragment, tabbar

I have a tab bar in my app with few buttons and for those button there is a fragment. On button click, I hide currently shown one and then show fragment corresponding to button clicked. Everything is ok, but sometimes when I return from another activity or have app in background for longer time then I see all those fragments stacked over themselves.

What is the reason for this behaviour and how should I fix it please?

**UPDATE 1:**

this is how I work with restoring instance state

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    mCurrentTab = 0;

    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    if (fragment1 != null)
        ft.show(fragment1);
    if (fragment2 != null)
        ft.hide(fragment2);
    if (fragment3 != null)
        ft.hide(fragment3);
    if (fragment4 != null)
        ft.hide(fragment4);
    if (fragment5 != null)
        ft.hide(fragment5);

    ft.commit();
}
```

and here is switching fragments in onTabbarButtonClick (all buttons have same listener)

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    // hide only what is needed and when it is needed
    // for example when user clicks currently selected tab then nothing is done
    switch (mCurrentTab) {
    case 1:
        if (v.getId() != R.id.btn1)
            ft.hide(fragment1);
        break;
    case 2:
        if (v.getId() != R.id.btn2)
            ft.hide(fragment2);
        break;
    case 3:
        if (v.getId() != R.id.btn3)
            ft.hide(fragment3);
        break;
    case 4:
        if (v.getId() != R.id.btn4)
            ft.hide(fragment4);
        break;
    case 5:
        if (v.getId() != R.id.btn5)
            ft.hide(fragment5);
        break;
    }

    // show only what is needed and when it is needed
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btn1:
        if (mCurrentTab != 1) {
            mCurrentTab = 1;
            ft.show(fragment1);
        }
        break;
    case R.id.btn2:
        if (mCurrentTab != 2) {
            mCurrentTab = 2;
            ft.show(fragment2);
        }
        break;
    case R.id.btn3:
        if (mCurrentTab != 3) {
            mCurrentTab = 3;
            ft.show(mFavoritesFragment3);
        }
        break;
    case R.id.btn4:
        if (mCurrentTab != 4) {
            mCurrentTab = 4;
            ft.show(fragment4);
        }
        break;
    case R.id.btn5:
        if (mCurrentTab != 5) {
            mCurrentTab = 5;
            ft.show(fragment5);
        }
        break;
    }

    ft.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but often these kind of issues is causes by the savedInstanceState being passed on in your activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

When you do this you also pass on the fragments which might not work too well with the way you've implemented your fragments (you haven't shown any code so really can't tell). You could try to simply use `super.onCreate(null);` but then you create everything from scratch every time.

Alternatively you should make it properly and remember the state of your fragments and set it when they are initialized.

Comment: hello, thanks for response :) I've edited my answer with some code example from my app. Is right way I did it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain that onRestoreInstanceState is always going to be called ? I am not certain that this is the case e.g. :

[Why onRestoreInstanceState() never gets called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574462/why-onrestoreinstancestate-never-gets-called)

The approach I use is the one described in here (see the section Adding Navigation Tabs):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html