# onRestoreInstanceState never called

Tags: android, parcelable, onsaveinstancestate

When my app goes into background I see `onSavedInstanceState` is called and I try to save an instance of an object using `Parcelable`. However, when my app returns to foreground, only `onResume` is called, never `onCreate` or `onRestoreInstanceState` although I save data in `onSavedInstanceState`. When I continue to use the app, the data is indeed lost and it crashes. Hence I need to make sure the state is recreated.

According to the documentation:

"The system calls onRestoreInstanceState() only if there is a saved state to restore, so you do not need to check whether the Bundle is null."

I see that `onSavedInstanceState` is called by the printout `-----Saving Session-----`.

The app crashes because some counters to positions in arrays are lost when entering `pause`-mode. So that is not really a problem, just shows I need to restore that state of the `Session`-instance.

EDIT: The app crashed due to a silly mistake by me. The data actually did not need to be saved. However, `onSaveInstanceState` is called, but never `onRestoreInstanceState` despite the documentation says so. I still do not understand that.

The life-cycle looks like:

```
OnPause
OnSaveInstanceState
OnStop
OnStart
OnResume
```

This is how I save the object:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putParcelable(SESSION_KEY, mSession);
    System.out.println(" -----  Saving Session  --------");
}
```

Restore:

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle bundle) {
    System.out.println("OnRestoreInstanceState");
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(bundle);
    String tmp = bundle.getString("TEST_KEY");
    System.out.println(tmp);
}
```

Implementing `Parcelable` in `Session`:

```
protected Session(Parcel in) {
    mFinalists = in.readArrayList(Finalist.class.getClassLoader());
    shootingOrder = in.readParcelable(ShootingOrder.class.getClassLoader());
    nbrshots = in.readInt();
    nextSession = in.readArrayList(Integer.class.getClassLoader());
    remaining = in.readArrayList(Integer.class.getClassLoader());
    eliminated = in.readArrayList(Integer.class.getClassLoader());
    circleIndex = in.readArrayList(Integer.class.getClassLoader());
    mOldStations = in.readArrayList(OldStations.class.getClassLoader());
}

public static final Creator<Session> CREATOR = new Creator<Session>() {
    @Override
    public Session createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        System.out.println("Restoring Session");
        return new Session(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Session[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Session[size];
    }
};

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeList(mFinalists);
    dest.writeParcelable(shootingOrder, flags);
    dest.writeInt(nbrshots);
    dest.writeList(nextSession);
    dest.writeList(remaining);
    dest.writeList(eliminated);
    dest.writeList(circleIndex);
    dest.writeList(mOldStations);
    dest.writeList(mCurrentStation);
    dest.writeList(mCurrentColors);
    boolean tmp[] = {isShootOff, isInitilized};
    dest.writeBooleanArray(tmp);
    dest.writeInt(sOffShots);

}
```

I also implement `Finalist`, `ShootingOrder` and `OldStation` as `Parcelable`:

```
protected Finalist(Parcel in) {
    int tmp[] = new int[100];
    in.readIntArray(tmp);
    mName = in.readString();
    mPosition = in.readInt();
    int resultSize = in.readInt();
    result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < resultSize; i++){
        result.add(tmp[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("Restoring Finalist");
}

public static final Creator<Finalist> CREATOR = new Creator<Finalist>() {
    @Override
    public Finalist createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Finalist(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Finalist[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Finalist[size];
    }
};

private int[] getResultArray(){
    int tmp[] = new int[result.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++){
        tmp[i] = result.get(i);
    }
    return tmp;
}
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    int tmp[] = getResultArray();
    dest.writeIntArray(tmp);
    dest.writeString(mName);
    dest.writeInt(mPosition);
    dest.writeInt(result.size());
}
```

Comment: You need to study activity life cycle in detail :). 
When application goes in background it doesn't exited it only goes into pause state. So when it comes to foreground `onResume()` method is called not `onRestoreInstanceState()`.

Comment: From the documentation: `The system calls onRestoreInstanceState() only if there is a saved state to restore, so you do not need to check whether the Bundle is null`. `--Saving Session--` is called, so something should be saved to the `bundle`.

Comment: It is not necessary that everytime onRestoreInstanceState() is called. You should try getting saved object in onResume() method instead of getting through onRestoreInstanceState().

Comment: You mentioned that your app crashes. Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: It crashes because of that I cannot restore the state of some counters to position in arrays, so that is not really a problem. Just a confirmation of that I need to save some data.

Comment: @Umair onRestoreInstanceState() is always called if a onSaveInstanceState() is made. However, I like to restore the state in `onCreate`, I think that it's easier this way.

Comment: @lucian nope it does not. I have been through this and trust me it's quite frustrating :).

Comment: @El_Loco why don't you use shared_preferences instead ?

Comment: @El_Loco Correct if I'm wrong, but this what I think it's happening: you save the data you need, in `onCreate` you get the data you saved, but for some reason the data associated with the arrays is not saved properly and crashes the app when used, right?

Comment: Well, I try to save it in `onSavedInstanceState`, then neither `onCreate` or `onRestoreInstanceState` is called. Since none of those methods are called, I never get the data back. I do not understand why `onRestoreInstanceState` is not called, when the documentation says it should.

Comment: Well, if the current activity is destroyed and should be recreated, then `onCreate` should definitely be called. If it's not called, then the activity is not created again because it is actually in memory (no need to do extra work). Something is really weird here: how is it that `onSaveInstanceState` is called and the others are not? Can you describe the scenario and if you have any developers settings activated (especially `Don't keep activities`)?

Comment: @Umair Is not `sharedPreferences` intended for saving data over longer time, like settings? According to the documentation it is expensive and it does not save objects.

Comment: I discovered I had made a very silly mistake, so the data was already saved. However, it does not answer why `onRestoreInstanceState` is not called although `onSaveInstanceState` is. Further, I still need to save the data when it is actually destroyed. I will check that now.

Comment: my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62966140/2828651) to get it called.